# Booktabs Table overflows the page

Tags: tables, booktabs, size, fit, overflow

Hope you’re all having a great day. I have the following table which just doesn’t fit the page, do you happen to know which command should I be using so that it fits the page? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage[roman, thin, thinp, thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setmarginsrb{2 cm}{1.5 cm}{2 cm}{1.5 cm}{0.25 cm}{0.5 cm}{0.25 cm}{0.5 cm}

\begin{document}

\section{Tabla de datos}

\begin{table}[h]

\begin{tabular}{@{}clcccc@{}  }
\toprule
Acelerómetro          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Clasificación}                                                                                                          & Sensibilidad                                                                                   & Bandwidth                                                              & Masa & Montaje/aplicación                                                                                                                                  \\ \midrule
PCB352C42             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial.\\ Señal de salida: Tensión. \\ Principio de Funcionamiento: Piezoeléctrico.\end{tabular}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}10.2 $\frac{mV}{m \dot s^{-2}}$\\ 100 $\frac{mV}{g}$\end{tabular}   & 1Hz-9kHz                                                               & 2.8g & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Magnético, Cera, Magnético \\ Setup de Bajo Perfil y/o Económico\end{tabular}                                            \\
Type 8305-001         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial. \\ Señal de salida: Tensión.\\ Principio de Funcionamiento: Piezoeléctrico.\end{tabular}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.110 $\frac{pC}{m \dot s^{-2}}$\\ 1.08 $\frac{pC}{g}$\end{tabular} & .2kHz a 10kHz                                                          & 26g  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Se monta Atornillado.\\ Se utiliza en laboratorio o para calibración.\end{tabular}                                       \\
MEM HIGH G 3501A202KG & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial. \\ Señal de Salida: Tensión. \\ Principio de Funcionamiento: Piezo-resistivo.\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.2 $\frac{mV}{g}$\\ 0.02 $\frac{mV}{m \dot s^{-2}}$\end{tabular}   & 0 a 10 kHz                                                             & 2g   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Montaje de superficie. \\ Se utiliza en Impacto de metal-metal, recolección de datos ente otros.\end{tabular}            \\
PDV-100               & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Referencia Fija. \\ Señal de Salida: Tensión. \\ Principio de Funcionamiento: Láser.\end{tabular}          & Rango de 5-25-125 $\frac{mm}{s \dot V^{-1}}$                                                   & 0.5Hz a 22kHz                                                          & N/A  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Contactless (Laser HeNe)\\ Se utiliza para medir velocidad.\end{tabular}                                                 \\
EVAL-ADXL335Z         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial. \\ Señal de salida: Tensión. \\ Principio de Funcionamiento: Capacitivo (MEM).\end{tabular} & 270-330 $\frac{mV}{g}$                                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Eje X/Y: 1600Hz\\ Eje Z: 550Hz\end{tabular} &      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Se monta Atornillado y/o pegado.\\ Se utiliza generalmente en celulares, sistemas de videojuegos, HDD, OIS.\end{tabular} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post some actual code, not an image of the code.

Comment: Given I’m new, Is it better if I post the entire document? Also, will the `code` option format the text as TEX automatically or do i have to do it in some other way?

Comment: Please post enough material -- a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) -- to generate the table whose layout you wish to fix. E.g., the preamble and the code of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: There we go, hope it is enough :)

Comment: Do you use the geometry package in your actual document? Your screenshot makes me suspect that you changed the margins. If so, please also include the corresponding setting in your MWE.

Comment: Risking putting too much code, I updated the entry with all the packages I normally use with my documents

Comment: Taking a look at the output of your document, I nnoticed a dot above some of the units. It is always teh second part of the unit in the demoninator of the fraction. Is this intentional or do you wanted a multiplication sign that links the two units there? I also wonder a bit about the use of something like "s^-2" in the denominator as well.

Comment: Looking at your image, I guess the table would already fit into the margins if you didn't use "Principio de Funcionamiento" everywhere, I think you can leave it out (it's obvious, imho, what "Piezoeléctrico" etc. mean here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- Load the `rotating` package and use its `sidewaystable` environment to typeset the table in landscape mode
- Use a `tabularx` environment and set its width to `\textwidth`
- Allow line breaks in all but the very narrow 5th column, and get rid of all interior `tabular` environments; use \newline directives where needed
- Load the `siunitx` package and use its `\si` and `\SI` macros to typeset scientific units

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{2 cm}{1.5 cm}{2 cm}{1.5 cm}{0.25 cm}{0.5 cm}{0.25 cm}{0.5 cm}

\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,seqsplit,ragged2e,tabularx}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % numbers and associated scientific units

%% define a few length parameters and column types
\newlength\lengthA
\newlength\lengthB
\newlength\lengthC
\newlength\lengthD
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}P{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
% Set values of length parameters:
\settowidth\lengthA{MEM HIGH G}
\settowidth\lengthB{Principio de Funcionamiento:}
\settowidth\lengthC{Rango de 5--25--}
\settowidth\lengthD{Eje X/Y: \SI{1600}{\hertz}}

\caption{Tabla de datos\strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
    P{\lengthA}
    Q{\lengthB}
    C{\lengthC}
    C{\lengthD}
    c
    L @{}  }
\toprule
  Acelerómetro
& Clasificación
& Sensibilidad 
& Bandwidth 
& Masa 
& Montaje\slash aplicación                                                                                                                                  \\ 
\midrule
PCB352C42             
&  Ref: Masa Inercial. \newline 
   Señal de salida: Tensión. \newline
   Principio de Funcionamiento: Piezoeléctrico.   
& \SI{10.2}{\milli\volt\per{\meter\second\tothe{-2}}} \newline 
  \SI{100}{\milli\volt\per\gram} 
& \SI{1}{\hertz}--\SI{9}{\kilo\hertz}
& \SI{2.8}{\gram} 
& Magnético, Cera, Magnético \newline 
  Setup de Bajo Perfil y/o Económico
\\ \addlinespace

\seqsplit{Type 8305-001}
& Ref: Masa Inercial. \newline
  Señal de salida: Tensión.\newline
  Principio de Funcionamiento: Piezoeléctrico.   
& \SI{0.110}{\pico\coulomb\per{\meter\second\tothe{-2}}}\newline
  \SI{1.08}{\pico\coulomb\per\gram}
& \SI{.2}{\kilo\hertz} a \SI{10}{\kilo\hertz}
& \SI{26}{\gram}  
& Se monta Atornillado. \newline
  Se utiliza en laboratorio o para calibración.
\\ \addlinespace

\seqsplit{MEM\ HIGH\ G\ 3501A202KG} 
& Ref: Masa Inercial. \newline
  Señal de Salida: Tensión. \newline
  Principio de Funcionamiento: Piezo-resistivo. 
& \SI{0.2}{\milli\volt\per\gram} \newline
  \SI{0.02}{\milli\volt\per{\meter\second\tothe{-2}}}
& $0$ a \SI{10}{\kilo\hertz}
& \SI{2}{\gram} 
& Montaje de superficie. \newline
  Se utiliza en Impacto de metal-metal, 
  recolección de datos ente otros.
\\ \addlinespace

PDV-100
& Ref: Referencia Fija. \newline
  Señal de Salida: Tensión. \newline
  Principio de Funcionamiento: Láser.         
& Rango de 5--25--125\,%
  \si{\milli\meter\per{\second\volt\tothe{-1}}} 
& \SI{0.5}{\hertz} a \SI{22}{\kilo\hertz}
& N/A  
& Contactless (Laser HeNe) \newline
  Se utiliza para medir velocidad.
\\ \addlinespace

\seqsplit{EVAL-ADXL335Z}      
& Ref: Masa Inercial. \newline
  Señal de salida: Tensión. \newline
  Principio de Funcionamiento: Capacitivo (MEM).
& 270--330\,\si{\milli\volt\per\gram}
& Eje X/Y: \SI{1600}{\hertz} \newline
  Eje Z: \SI{550}{\hertz}
& --
& Se monta Atornillado y/o pegado. \newline
  Se utiliza generalmente en celulares, 
  sistemas de videojuegos, HDD, OIS.
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a first rough version that might serve as a point to start from. In addition to making the table fit into the available space, please also consider using `siunitx` (you already load it) for the number unit combinations instead of math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{2 cm}{1.5 cm}{2 cm}{1.5 cm}{0.25 cm}{0.5 cm}{0.25 cm}{0.5 cm}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}

\section{Tabla de datos}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcccX@{}  }
\toprule
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{Clasificación}                                                                                                          & Sensibilidad                                                                                   & Bandwidth                                                              & Masa & Montaje/aplicación                                                                                                                                  \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Acelerómetro: PCB352C42 }\\            
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial.\\ SdS: Tensión. \\ PdF: Piezoeléctrico.\end{tabular}    
  & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}10.2 $\frac{mV}{m \dot s^{-2}}$\\ 100 $\frac{mV}{g}$\end{tabular}   
  & 1Hz-9kHz                                                               
  & 2.8g 
  & Magnético, Cera, Magnético\newline  Setup de Bajo Perfil y/o Económico \\ \addlinespace
  
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Acelerómetro: Type 8305-001} \\        
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial. \\ SdS: Tensión.\\ PdF: Piezoeléctrico.\end{tabular}    
  & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}0.110 $\frac{pC}{m \dot s^{-2}}$\\ 1.08 $\frac{pC}{g}$\end{tabular} 
  & .2kHz a 10kHz                                                          
  & 26g  
  & Se monta Atornillado.\newline Se utiliza en laboratorio o para calibración.                                       \\  \addlinespace
  
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Acelerómetro: MEM HIGH G 3501A202KG} \\
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial. \\ SdS: Tensión. \\ PdF: Piezo-resistivo.\end{tabular}  
  & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}0.2 $\frac{mV}{g}$\\ 0.02 $\frac{mV}{m \dot s^{-2}}$\end{tabular}   
  & 0 a 10 kHz                                                             
  & 2g   
  & Montaje de superficie. \newline Se utiliza en Impacto de metal-metal, recolección de datos ente otros.            \\  \addlinespace
  
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Acelerómetro: PDV-100}  \\             
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Referencia Fija. \\ SdS: Tensión. \\ PdF: Láser.\end{tabular}          
  & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Rango de \\ 5-25-125 $\frac{mm}{s \dot V^{-1}}$\end{tabular}
  & 0.5Hz a 22kHz                                                          
  & N/A  
  & Contactless (Laser HeNe)\newline Se utiliza para medir velocidad. \\  \addlinespace
  
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Acelerómetro: EVAL-ADXL335Z}\\         
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Ref: Masa Inercial. \\ SdS: Tensión. \\ PdF: Capacitivo (MEM).\end{tabular} 
  & 270-330 $\frac{mV}{g}$                                                                         
  & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Eje X/Y: 1600Hz\\ Eje Z: 550Hz\end{tabular} 
  &      
  & Se monta Atornillado y/o pegado.\newline Se utiliza generalmente en celulares, sistemas de videojuegos, HDD, OIS. \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Ref = reference; SdS = Señal de salida; PdF = Principio de Funcionamiento}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```